# С 0 и -5 получилось, дальше выдает только 'Odd negative number'. Как сделать ? Спасибо

Tags: javascript, функции

Напишите функцию describesNumber, которая принимает аргумент number и возвращает описание числа: 'Even positive number', 'Even negative number', 'Odd positive number', 'Odd negative number', 'Zero'.

Примеры:
функция describesNumber(48) должна возвратить 'Even posotive number';
функция describesNumber(-12) должна возвратить 'Even negative number';
функция describesNumber(51) должна возвратить 'Odd posotive number';
функция describesNumber(-5) должна возвратить 'Odd negative number';
функция describesNumber(0) должна возвратить 'Even posotive number';

```js
function describesNumber(number) {
  if (number === 0) return 'Zero';
  if (-5 <= 0) return 'Odd negative number';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function describesNumber(num) {
  let res;
  if (num > 0) res = num % 2 == 0 ? 'Even positive number' : 'Odd positive number';
  else if (num < 0) res = num % 2 == 0 ? 'Even negative number' : 'Odd negative number';
  else res = 'Zero';
  return res;
}

console.log(48, describesNumber(48));
console.log(-12, describesNumber(-12));
console.log(51, describesNumber(51));
console.log(-5, describesNumber(-5));
console.log(0, describesNumber(0));
```

Или можно так )

```js
function describesNumber(num, res = 'Zero') {
      if (num > 0) res = num % 2 == 0 ? 'Even positive number' : 'Odd positive number';
      else if (num < 0) res = num % 2 == 0 ? 'Even negative number' : 'Odd negative number';
      return res;
    }

    console.log(48, describesNumber(48));
    console.log(-12, describesNumber(-12));
    console.log(51, describesNumber(51));
    console.log(-5, describesNumber(-5));
    console.log(0, describesNumber(0));
```

Comment: Как вариант: `return \`${num == 0 ? "Zero" : (num % 2 == 0 ? "Even" : "Odd")} ${num >= 0 ? "positive" : "negative"} number\`;`

Comment: @AlexKrass ну или так, но сразу видно что автор новенький в программирование, так что не надо его нагружать) и ваш ответ очень коротенький)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function describesNumber (number) {
  // проверка на ноль, так как это уникальный случай
  if (number === 0) return 'Zero';
  
  // проверка на положительное число  
  let positivity = '';
  if (number > 0) {
    positivity = 'positive';
  } else {
    positivity = 'negative';
  }
  // проверка на четность  
  let oddity = '';
  if (number % 2 !== 0) {
    oddity = 'Odd';
  } else {
    oddity = 'Even';
  }
  
  //собираем строку вместе  
  return `${oddity} ${positivity} number`
}

console.log(48, describesNumber(48));
console.log(-12, describesNumber(-12));
console.log(51, describesNumber(51));
console.log(-5, describesNumber(-5));
console.log(0, describesNumber(0));
```